# Performance discussion in Android application with sync feature

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite

I'm currently developing a forum like application.

In order to provide offline usage, i have maintained all the **Posts** viewed by the by user in the descending order of the modified time.

So when the user comments over the posts, the modified time get changed.

So when i query for the latest posts, the posts i have stored in my sqlite database is again retrieved.

Functional i need it.

But i need some info and best practices in syncing the data in this scenario.

I came up with following solutions,

1. As brute force method, we need to check if the same post id exists in the local database before insert else update everytime with sql.
2. Store the Post information of all the posts to a hash map. Check if newer post id is present in the cache. Invalidate the cache for every insert in the local database.

Any better choice is welcome.

Thanks & Regards,
Siva N B